# C# How to populate aspx Textbox with textmode=datetimelocal from a datable row cell

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

I have been trying to solve this problem for hours and I have not been anywhere close to solving it.

What happens is that I'm trying to populate the control below

```
<asp:TextBox ID = "TxtDateReceived" runat = "server" 
CssClass = "TxtFont" Width = "300px" Height = "25px" 
TextMode = "DateTimeLocal"> </asp:TextBox>
```

With the value stored in a cell in the row of a data table, as shown below (dt is loaded with a method that pulls sql data, plus I am already sure that `dt.Rows[0][7]` it's not empty)

```
TxtDateReceived.Text = dt.Rows[0][7].ToString();
```

The data in `dt.Rows[0][7]` is  `8/18/2018 13:38:00`

PD this is what I am getting when it is trying to populate the field

[image]

Comment: It's working well if you have valid data in dt.Rows[0][7].It's not problem with your TextBox I have check through following code.
string data = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        TxtDateReceived.Text = data;

Comment: What you are facing in your problem ??It's been populating absolutly well..

Comment: It doesn´t do it on mines see picture below

Comment: I meant above sorry!!

Comment: Check dt.Rows[0][7].Is that showing value in date format?  as you described because it's working for me.I have added in dataTable few Rows of date and getting it well

Comment: I have checked like 1000 times and it keeps showing a valid datetime,, What browser are you using Arslan ?

Comment: I'm using Firefox quite well

Answer (score 0):

I have been taken **DataTable** with few temporary Rows of **Date Format** and It's working absolutely well for me.

**C# Tested Code**

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("Date");
    for(int i=18;i<21;i++)
    {
        table.Rows.Add("8/"+i+"/2018 13:38:00");
    }
    TxtDateReceived.Text = table.Rows[2][0].ToString();
```

**Aspx Design**

```
<asp:TextBox ID = "TxtDateReceived" runat = "server" 
    CssClass = "TxtFont" Width = "300px" Height = "25px" 
    TextMode = "DateTimeLocal"> </asp:TextBox>
```

**Output Result**
[image]

Further,it maybe problem in fetching data from sql or maybe other conflicts but it's working as well shown you.

Comment: I also think so let me see I have an idea you are using edge or internet explorer

Comment: Firefox tested result

Comment: try to run it in chrome or in firefox and let me know if you will get positive results please

Comment: Working well for all other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this same thing when I had to call gridview data to a text box. But I've done it a bit differently and it works well for me.

```
TxtDateReceived.Text = dt.Rows[0][7].ToString();

My version:
if (e.CommandName == "Select")
{
  Int32 num = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument); //This just needs to be done once.
    TxtDateReceived.Text = dt.Rows[num].Cells[cell number].Text;
}
```

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for. But judging by your problem it sounds very close to the one I had awhile back.

Answer (score 0):

Found this answer elsewhere (for future reference).

Although date/time is shown mm/dd/yyyy in the text box, it has to actually be formatted `yyyy-MM-dd` to be populated from the Code Behind. And only in Chrome too. For me at least.

Not sure about time format. For my application, I only needed date, and Chrome would not populate the value from code behind if I would pass it as `MM/dd/yyyy`.

For example, in my case:

```
        tbDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

That worked.